# Am getting an error message while using this connection type MS SQL Server (Native)

Tags: sql-server

Error message is like login failed for the user. But using the same user and credentials we were trying to connect the DB using MS SQL Server Connection type.

It is throwing errors only when connection type is changed to MS SQL Server (Native)

Comment: From what tool? Management Studio? SSIS? Something else? What does the connection string look like? SQL Server doesn't make connections by itself (except for linked servers, but there you don't get to pick a type when connecting to another SQL Server).

Comment: Maybe provide us with a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Time to ask one of your seniors or dbas in your giant firm to help.

Comment: Pentaho tool am trying to connect locally,

Comment: Error connecting to database: (using class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver) Login failed for a service account user user ClientConnectionId:ed616268-2a16-4f8d-8bb1-5f3e3812340e

Comment: above one was the error screenshot